# Save twilio recordings to database using recordingStatusCallback

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need to save the call recording details including the audio file to database while making a call.

This is my twiML file.

```
<Response>
    <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual" recordingStatusCallback="https://example.com/record_data.php" action="https://example.com/test.php" callerId="xxxxxxxxxx">
          xxxxxxxxxx
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

What should I do in *record_data.php* file to save the recorded details to the database?

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @philnash..I'm making a call from browser to my mobile and is getting recorded and listed in https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/recordings. How can I access recorded call with `recordingStatusCallback` url ?

Comment: Right, but have you tried to use PHP to save the file yet?

Comment: Have you tried Googling?

Comment: yes..I understood only upto this; we can use `recordingStatusCallback` to  get a webhook with all the recording details when the recording is available for access. Couldn't find any example on how to access these details in `recordingStatusCallback` page.

Comment: @Jenz : Have you figured it out Jenz? Because I've been banging my head over this for days now. Twilio documentation is not very clear. How do I retrieve the recording for the call with PHP? Can you help with this please?

Comment: @Jenz have you find any solution to retrieve the recording at recordingStatusCallback url?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you receive the `recordingStatusCallback` webhook, Twilio will send the [following parameters in the body of the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback-parameters).

```
AccountSid          The unique identifier of the Account responsible for this recording.
CallSid             A unique identifier for the call associated with the recording. This will always refer to the parent leg of a two leg call.
RecordingSid        The unique identifier for the recording.
RecordingUrl        The URL of the recorded audio.
RecordingStatus     The status of the recording. Possible values are: completed.
RecordingDuration   The length of the recording, in seconds.
RecordingChannels   The number of channels in the final recording file as an integer. Possible values are 1, 2.
RecordingSource     The type of call that created this recording. For recordings initiated when record is set on <Dial>, DialVerb is returned.
```

The `RecordingUrl` is where you can download the recording from to store on your own server.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @philnash..I have just tried with print_r($_REQUEST) in the recordingStatusCallback page. But it is not printing anything. Can I see the data before storing into the server?

Comment: It's showing nothing at all? Is that as the result of Twilio making the request? Can you try pointing your recordingStatusCallback URL at http://requestb.in/ and inspecting the result there?

Comment: Tried that. There I'm getting the recorded details.

Comment: Ok, so that is what Twilio will be sending to your server when it makes the webhook. I'm not sure what else I can do here.